# Without ebook creation software, can I fix formatting issues on an epub?

Tags: epub

I have an epub copy of a book where all the lines are broken up wrong, and it ends up looking like really bad free form poetry. This makes the book really hard to read. Is there a way for me to fix this sort of problem on my own, without having some sort of software to make ebooks, or am I stuck just trying to find a version of this particular book without this problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by ebook creation software. You can always:

1. Rename the epub to a zip (change the `epub` suffix of the filename to `zip`)
2. Extract the zip file.
3. Manually edit the extracted `HTML` files with your favorite text editor - this assumes that you have an understanding of formatting with `HTML`
4. Repackage the files/folder to zip again
5. Rename the `zip` to `epub` again. (As [user3019828](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/users/155/user3019828) pointed out in a comment: you need to use a zipper that won't compress the mimetype file. For Windows, ePubPack is an option; for Mac, you can use ePub Zip.)

The above steps does not involve any specific ebook creation software... But you should give a try to [Calibre's heuristics fixing capabilities](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#heuristic-processing) too. And Calibre also has a [GUI to refine ebook contents](http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/edit.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You say you don't have access to an ebook generation software; why not change that?

Free software [Sigil](http://code.google.com/p/sigil/) allows you to open, edit and save EPUB ebooks, so you don't have to disassemble the file yourself.